# Constructing a query that gives the percent of values within a given range after entering the range for the first time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

Using SQL Server Express 2014. sidenote: My 'p' button is acting up, so forgive me if I miss a few.

To find the percent of values inside a range `[a,b]`, I would use the query:

```
SELECT 100.0*COUNT([value])/1.0*COUNT(*) FROM [table] WHERE [value] >= a AND [value] <= b
```

If, instead, I wanted to find the percent of values within the range, starting from when the values first hit that range (not including those initial values in our lower count), how would I do that?

Example:

```
48, 10, 25, 31, 42, 26, 14, 28
```

Range of `[26,35]`

First three values are outside the range (one is above, two below), so they get chucked. New data set is:

```
31, 42, 26, 14, 28
```

3 of the 5 remaining values are in the range, so the query should return `60.0`.

Comment: Can you set up a procedure? Or must it be a single query?

Comment: It doesn't need to be in a single query. Just needs to happen!

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code:

```
Var startingcounter = 0
Var inrange counter = 0

On input
  if inrange then 
    startingcounter = + 1
  if startingcounter > 0 then
    if inrange then
      inrangecounter = +1
On end input 
  return inrangecounter/startingcounter*100.0
```

Does this give you enough to work with?

Comment: Yes, I think so! I want to generate a table of these from another table's values. The second table has a compound key (id,cycle), and (values) from which I want to find the percentage. The end result would be a table with [id],[percentage]; the percentage in the range after entering the range for a given simulation ID. What would this look like? I'm still stuck in a C-like mindset, thinking I'm going to have to create an array, run the query using a `SELECT .. WHERE id = k` inside a for loop iterating over `k`. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Are there always the same number of values in each record?

Comment: It varies. When I get a chance, I'll edit the OP with the query I have for the overall percent in range.